# How to send parameter to preprocessor in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have implemented PrimeFaces custom data exporter as:

```
<p:commandLink id="pdf" ajax="false" rendered="#{documentProcessor.isPDFVisible}">
    <p:graphicImage value="/res/img/pdf_icon.png" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true" target="#{exporterController.customExporter}" />
    <pe:exporter preProcessor="#{documentProcessor.preProcessPDF}" type="pdf" target="compListTable" fileName="File_PDF" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Please point me as how can I send parameter(s) in `documentProcessor.preProcessPDF` method?

Comment: By simply `documentProcessor.preProcessPDF(param1, param2)`, if your method accepts.

Comment: the method is preProcessPDF(Object document) document is sent by primefaces thats why it has been used as property, if i am not wrong, i tried to send parameter as you mentioned then document is not sent.

Comment: `preProcessPDF` isn't your custom method?

Comment: it is a standard method. I don't know if this could receive parameter. Source : https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/customExporter.jsf

Comment: Okay, and what does your `exporterController.customExporter` do?

Comment: it adds some header in the pdf above the datatable

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution to pass a parameter to the processor method, but I used a actionListener and postprocessor and it worked! Tests if for preprocessor works too.

```
<p:commandLink immediate="true" ajax="false"
        actionListener="#{documentProcessor.downloadTypeGenerator}">
        <f:attribute name="type" value="#{downloadType}" />
        <p:graphicImage name="icons/excel_icon.png" library="img" width="24" />
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="#{target}" fileName="#{fileName}"
            postProcessor="#{documentProcessor.excelDownloadPostProcessor}" />
    </p:commandLink>
```

Backend: 
(downloadType  is a global variable.)

```
public void downloadTypeGenerator(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            downloadType = (String) actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("type");
    }

public void excelDownloadPostProcessor(Object document) {
   if(downloadType != null && downloadType .equalsIgnoreCase("myValue")){
     //action...
   }
}
```